# android sms contact name

Tags: android, cursor, sms, contacts

I have been searching for days now on why this is not working. I am trying to get the sender number and name of the text message, but it always returns as zero or it's always the same exact number no matter who text me. And the name is always blank.

```
Cursor cur = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uriReceive, null, null, null,null);

while (cur.moveToNext()) 
{
                   int index_Address = cur.getColumnIndex("address");
                   int index_Person = cur.getColumnIndex("person");

                   strAddress = cur.getString(index_Address);  
                   intPerson = cur.getString(index_Person); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're reading existing SMSes (not just incoming new ones)

```
    String columns[] = new String[] { "_id", "date", "address", "subject", "body" };

    Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), columns, whereClause, bindVars, "date desc");
    //Only want newest, so only handle first item in cursor
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        long date = cursor.getLong(1);
        String address = cursor.getString(2);
        String subject = cursor.getString(3);
        String body = cursor.getString(4);
                    //Handle message here
            }while(cursor.moveToNext())
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Then to turn address into a name, you'd need to cross-reference address with the contacts database.